# Converting a String to a Boolean in Python

Tags: python, string, boolean

How to convert a String to a Boolean? For example:

```
str = "False and False or True and True"
str = "( "+str+" )"
str = str.replace("and",") and (")
```

returns

```
str == '( False ) and ( False or True ) and ( True )'
```

How to execute `str` for result 'False'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval):

```
>>> eval('( False ) and ( False or True ) and ( True )')
False
```

**Notes**:

- don't use `eval` on user input, see e.g. [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) and
- don't use `str` as a variable name; it shadows a Python built-in.

Comment: Thank you, jonrsharpe :)

Comment: This works but I thought someone should mention the issues with eval: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function that tranlates appropriate strings to True and False

```
def str2bool(self, v): # Note the self to allow it to be in a class
  return v.lower() in ('yes', 'true', 't', '1', 'yea', 'verily')  # lower() is a method
```

This will allow you to analyze various user inputs as well.